# inferring types from an Error throwing function in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function below, that checks if `myValue` exists before calling `doSomething()`, if it does not exist, it will throw. Typescript accepts this...

```
function myFunction(){
   if (!myValue) {
     const error = Error(errorName);
     error.name = errorName.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase();
     throw error;
   }

   const something = doSomething(myValue);
}
```

The below implementation makes a Helper Function for throwing a named Error. Typescript doesn't like this, and errors that `doSomething(myValue)` is being passed `myValue` which is potentially undefined. How can I type the `namedError` so that it has the inferred typing from above, that it is Truthy?

```
function myFunction(){
   if (!myValue) {
     namedError("my value doesn't exist");
   }

   const something = doSomething(myValue);
}

function namedError(errorName: string){
  const error = Error(errorName);
  error.name = errorName.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase();
  throw error;
};
```

Comment: What if you `return namedError(...)`, in your `if` statement?

Comment: that changes the type of the entire function and isn't what it should do. I'm throwing, not returning. This changes the function from `Promise<MyType>` to `Promise<MyType | Undefined>`

Comment: Have you tried to mark the return type of `namedError` to `never`?

Comment: it already has type of  `never`

Comment: Please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE.   The issue is likely dependent on the declared types of `myValue` and `doSomething()`, which have not been included here.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Since typescript [3.7](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695) functions that return `never` have the same impact in control flow analysis as a `throw` expression. So this will work:

```
let myValue: string | undefined;

function myFunction() {
  if (!myValue) {
    namedError("my value doesn't exist");
  }

  const something = doSomething(myValue);
}

function namedError(errorName: string): never {
  const error = Error(errorName);
  error.name = errorName.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase();
  throw error;
};

function doSomething(value: string) {

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAGwpgLgBAtgngNQIYgK5gFxQM4QE4CWAdgOZQA+UqRAJmAGbFg0Dcww91AxhAQPZFYcAGLdeAgBQBKKAG9gUKAXpQJAQnjI0YGfMWKiSGMwCiePHzwSARPCgA3FOig0+YbEQDk0MAA8CuNZSbIoAvuyKXAK4OHzGEAAWxGQAvC58AMpxkEmkEppOOmzhHGL8gobGNGYWVmDmlgByRpg4+MlSWERg9vVyClBRRDH1tVBpNZYSo00twQMzeAB0lWDjUIvNxkt4YAAOIEhcYBIA9AA62ADUpyQANFDWALRBSxB8ADJ8AO71AMJIbAneaKRIWb4bBp4YpsUpEHjldJZeK5EgSRzaLC4QikXTsUJAA)

Answer (score -1):

Typescript null elimination doesn't work with nest function calls (unless it's an immediately invoked function expression) hence the error.
You can either move the doSomething invocation into an else block, or use the type assertion operator when you are sure a value will not be null or defined.

So either:

```
if (!myValue) {
  namedError(...)
} else {
  const something = doSomething(myValue);
}
```

or

```
if (!myValue) {
  namedError(...)
}

// use type assertion (! postfix) to tell compiler that the value will never be null or undefined
const something = doSomething(myValue!);
```